# ArrayList shows it's size is 0 even after adding elements to it

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList to store instances of fragments. This ArrayList named 'listofFragInstances' is global. I have added values to this ArrayList in `setUpViewPager()` method. 
But while using it in another method outside the `setUpViewPager()`  method, it's size shows zero on using debugger, while it's size inside the `setUpViewPager()` method is as expected. What's the problem?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.audit_form_activity);   

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);


        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_categories);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        //       Outside Loop
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

//        Get the JSON Data from DataSource


        try {
            JSONObject pageObj = new JSONObject(page);
            JSONArray auditQuestionsArray = pageObj.getJSONArray("AuditQuestions");
            int auditQuestionsArrayLength = auditQuestionsArray.length();
            no_of_categories = auditQuestionsArrayLength;


//        Outer-Loop Through the CategoryNames to Create Fragments for each CategoryName.

            for (int i = 0; i < no_of_categories; i++) {
                JSONObject auditQuestionsArrayObject = auditQuestionsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                category = auditQuestionsArrayObject.getString("categoryName");


                Tab1 myFrag = Tab1.newInstance(category);
                listOfFragInstances.add(myFrag);

                adapter.addFrag(myFrag, category);

            }
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

public void activity_saveAll()
{
    for (int i=0; i<listOfFragInstances.size(); i++)
    {
        listOfFragInstances.get(i).saveAnswers();
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Is `activity_saveAll` is in the same activity or fragment? Is this the only place where you are using the `listOfFragInstances`?

Comment: It is in the same activity. I have tried to call this method in fragment.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible that you are calling it from the Fragment before the data is available from your network call? Please show us how you have called it from the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that the ViewPager handles the lifecycle of the Fragments meaning that the instance you store in the ArrayList may not be the same as the one being used by the ViewPager.

The recommendation in not to keep instances of the Fragment and let the ViewPager do its job. To be honest, I have never been able to live with this. To overcome you problem you need to extend the FragmentManager and replace the instance in the ArrayList when the ViewPager changes it internally.

This is one I use.

The relevant code is `public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` which replaces the Fragment in the ArrayList when a new Fragment is instantiated. This is not my authoring, I got it from another question here in SO but can't remember which one.

To get the right current fragment instance use `public Fragment getCurrentIntance(int position)`.

It may be obvious but just in case, don't keep references to the Fragments outside of this class because you can't know if they are current or not.

```
public class MySimplePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    protected final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    protected final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    protected final HashMap<Integer,Fragment> currentInstances = new HashMap<>();
    protected FragmentManager fm;

    public MySimplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        this.fm = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    //Method to add Tab fragment and Tab name
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        currentInstances.put(position, createdFragment);
        // save the appropriate reference depending on position
        return createdFragment;
    }

    public Fragment getCurrentIntance(int position){
        return currentInstances.get(position);
    }
}
```